# What does this Perl regex mean: m/(.*?):(.*?)$/g?

Tags: regex, perl

I am editing a Perl file, but I don't understand this regexp comparison. Can someone please explain it to me?

```
if ($lines =~ m/(.*?):(.*?)$/g) { } ..
```

What happens here? `$lines` is a line from a text file.

Comment: Looks like first `(.*?)` will always match to empty string.

Comment: Not always. It'll match all characters up to the first colon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Break it up into parts:

```
$lines =~ m/ (.*?)      # Match any character (except newlines)
                        # zero or more times, not greedily, and
                        # stick the results in $1.
             :          # Match a colon.
             (.*?)      # Match any character (except newlines)
                        # zero or more times, not greedily, and
                        # stick the results in $2.
             $          # Match the end of the line.
           /gx;
```

So, this will match strings like `":"` (it matches zero characters, then a colon, then zero characters before the end of the line, `$1` and `$2` are empty strings), or `"abc:"` (`$1 = "abc"`, `$2` is an empty string), or `"abc:def:ghi"` (`$1 = "abc"` and `$2 = "def:ghi"`).

And if you pass in a line that doesn't match (it looks like this would be if the string does not contain a colon), then it won't process the code that's within the brackets. But if it does match, then the code within the brackets can use and process the special `$1` and `$2` variables (at least, until the next regular expression shows up, if there is one within the brackets).

Answer (score 10):

There is a tool to help understand regexes: [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAPE::Regex::Explain).

Ignoring the `g` modifier, which is not needed here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;

my $re = qr/(.*?):(.*?)$/;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new($re)->explain();

__END__

The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(.*?):(.*?)$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See also [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Answer (score 3):

It was written by someone who either knows too much about regular expressions or not enough about the [`$'`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#$POSTMATCH) and [$`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#$PREMATCH) variables.

THis could have been written as

```
if ($lines =~ /:/) {
    ... # use $` ($PREMATCH)  instead of $1
    ... # use $' ($POSTMATCH) instead of $2
}
```

or

```
if ( ($var1,$var2) = split /:/, $lines, 2 and defined($var2) ) {
    ... # use $var1, $var2 instead of $1,$2
}
```

Comment: If you want to use /:/, use the /p flag and the ${^PREMATCH} and ${^POSTMATCH} variables from Perl 5.10. I'd prefer split, though, since that's what's actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

`(.*?)` captures any characters, but as few of them as possible.

So it looks for patterns like `<something>:<somethingelse><end of line>`, and if there are multiple `:` in the string, the first one will be used as the divider between `<something>` and `<somethingelse>`.

Answer (score 2):

That line says to perform a regular expression match on `$lines` with the regex `m/(.*?):(.*?)$/g`. It will effectively return `true` if a match can be found in `$lines` and `false` if one cannot be found.

An explanation of the `=~` operator:

> Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression
>   to a pattern match. Certain operations
>   search or modify the string $_ by
>   default. This operator makes that kind
>   of operation work on some other
>   string. The right argument is a search
>   pattern, substitution, or
>   transliteration. The left argument is
>   what is supposed to be searched,
>   substituted, or transliterated instead
>   of the default $_. When used in scalar
>   context, the return value generally
>   indicates the success of the
>   operation.

The regex itself is:

```
m/    #Perform a "match" operation
(.*?) #Match zero or more repetitions of any characters, but match as few as possible (ungreedy)
:     #Match a literal colon character
(.*?) #Match zero or more repetitions of any characters, but match as few as possible (ungreedy)
$     #Match the end of string
/g    #Perform the regex globally (find all occurrences in $line)
```

So if `$lines` matches against that regex, it will go into the conditional portion, otherwise it will be `false` and will skip it.